# How much time should I allow, as a US resident, to catch a domestic flight from JFK after arriving from Scotland

Tags: us-residents

How much time should I allow, as a US resident, to catch a domestic flight from JFK after arriving from Scotland. On a Tuesday afternoon in Oct.

Comment: Incidentally, being a US resident doesn't change the answer all that much.  For international travelers from countries that don't require visas, it's not a lot slower to go through the process.

Comment: Jim, in my experience the non-US lines can be significantly longer and slower that the US-citizen lines. One see the US-only lines clear and then they start pulling from the non-citizen lines. Things do vary a lot though. On some occasions we seem to zip through.

Comment: @djna it depends on the airport. I have GOES entry and have literally sat and waited behind Chinese students at the DFW airport. I had to complain to get someone to help and it was not faster at all.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the details.

If it's a single booking, your booking is automatically "legal" and you have a good chance of making it. It's not guaranteed (it never is), but if something goes wrong the airline will put you on the next available flight for free.

Things go a LOT faster if you have Global Entry and TSA pre-check. Highly recommended for a tight connection.

I'd say 2.5 hours gives a pretty good margin. With Global Entry, pre-check & no checked luggage 90 minutes should work as well.

If it's two separate bookings, I'd go with a minimum of 4 hours. 6 would be safer, since there is a lot of money at stake. If you miss you connection (delay, weather, lost bags, immigration issues) you are a "no show" and may have to buy a completely new ticket.